# Indent back button on UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

Is there any way to indent the default back button on a UINavigationBar? Basically I just want to move it about 10pts right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better hide the default back button and add a custom back button on the navigation bar.

All the Best.

Comment: lol, I've only just got it all working the way I wanted it! :p no chance! haha, thanks for your help though.

Comment: Not possible... You'll have to do this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hiding the default back button worked for me, using a UIButton which you can style anyway you want:

```
...
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
UIBarButtonItem *fixedspace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixedspace.width = 10.0f;

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixedspace, backButtonItem, nil];
...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way. But you could get the navigation bar object:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [navController navigationBar];
```

...and maybe iterate through it's subviews. I presume you could determine which subview is the back button based on it's frame property.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this thread and is using iOS5, this seemed to work for me:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1.0f, 0.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Sorry, I just thought about that, you wanted to move the whole button right. This is just the text inside the button.